# Add additional acceptable variables in VF page

Tags: visualforce

This VF page is for a custom button that currently only works if the opp is in 'Approved' stage. I need it to also work if the opp is in 'SOW Received' or 'Closed Won'. How would I add those into the variable that looks for it to be 'Accepted'?

```
<apex:page standardController="Campaign_Design_Profile__c">
<script> 
    window.onload = docusign;
    function docusign(){
    var approved='{!Campaign_Design_Profile__c.Opportunity_Stage__c}'; 
    if (approved=='Approved')
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit, are you looking to fetch the the stage value in the JS and then verify if its one of approved, sow received or closed won?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could do this, but in Visualforce, it's usually easier to use the formula syntax:

```
<apex:page standardController="Campaign_Design_Profile__c">
<script>
  window.onload = docusign;
  function docusign(){
    if ({!1=CASE(Campaign_Design_Profile__c.Opportunity_Stage__c,
          'Approved',1,'SOW Received',1,'Closed Won',1,0)}) {
```

Where:

## 1 = CASE(...)

We use this technique to get a value and compare it to 1; this outputs true or false

## CASE(Field, Value1, Output1, ..., Default)

We use CASE to compare a field to many different values, with the final value being the default value.

## Not A String

We remove the quotation marks so we don't end up with `"false"`, which is actually *true* in JavaScript (only values like `false` or `0` are actually "false" values).

I strongly recommend using this form when possible, as it greatly reduces syntax errors.

---

In plain JavaScript, you just use the "||" (OR) operator:

```
if(approved=='Approved' || approved=='SOW Received' || approved=='Closed Won') {
```